# Showing Operation object (1) when trying to get foreignkey Django

Tags: html, django

I am trying to post a table in HTML and I get This "Operation object (1)" instead of just the id "1" How is possible to fix this

as you can see in the picture where is selected I want to have the id, not text
models.py

```
class Operation(models.Model):
    operationID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    assignee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dateRegistered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    timeStart = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    timeFinish = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(
        'Status', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Subtask(models.Model):
    subtaskID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    operationID = models.ForeignKey('Operation', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    containerID = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    containerWeightT = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    loadSeq = models.IntegerField()
    moveTo = models.ForeignKey('MoveTo', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stow = models.ForeignKey('Stow', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.ForeignKey(
        'Status', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def displaydata(request):
    results1 = Subtask.objects.prefetch_related(
        'moveTo', 'operationID', 'stow', 'status').all()

    return render(request, 'ee.html', {'Subtask': results1})
```

This is my HTML code to post the data from the database. I just posted where the table is and removed lines that contains CSS/JS

```
        <table id="blbbl" class="display">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="">ID</th>
                <th class="">OperationID</th>
                <th class="">ContinerID</th>
                <th class="">Weight</th>
                <th class="">LoadSeq</th>
                <th class="">MoveTo</th>
                <th class="">Stow</th>
                <th class="">Status</th>
                <th class="">Edit</th>
                <th class="">Delete</th>
                <th class="">Add New</th>

              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {% for Subtask in Subtask %}
              <tr>
                <td class="">{{Subtask.subtaskID}}</td>
                <td class="">{{Subtask.operationID}}</td>
                <td class="">{{Subtask.containerID}}</td>
                <td class="">{{Subtask.containerWeightT}}</td>
                <td class="">{{Subtask.loadSeq}}</td>
                <td class="">{{Subtask.moveTo}}</td>
                <td class="">{{Subtask.stow}}</td>
                <td class="">{{Subtask.status}}</td>

                <td>
                  <a href="{% url 'updatesubtask' Subtask.subtaskID %}" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a href="{% url 'deletesubtask' Subtask.subtaskID %}" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <a href="{% url 'addsubtask' %}" role="button"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="color: green;"></i></a>
                </td>


              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

[website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWFdd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Insıde your Operation model add a int* function:

```
class Operation(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    ...

    def __int__(self):
        return self.operationID
```

*: int not str

Comment: I have tried that but i get this error msg: __str__ returned non-string (type int)

Comment: I tried your new solution as well, but it still doesn't change from "Operation object(1)" to "1"

Comment: Can you edit your question  to add your html code?

Comment: I posted the Code with the table only beacause i had to write more info but dont know what

Comment: in the views.py you return Subtask but I didnt see this on html for loop

Comment: try    {% for Operation in Subtask %}

Comment: ohh sorry this was the wrong table. this one is working fine